# Should a light tunnel be positioned facing east or west?

Tags: lighting, solar-tubes

I want to install a light tunnel to increase the light in my kitchen. Above this room there is a roof with one side facing east and the other side facing west. Would I get more light from a light tunnel fitted to an east or west facing roof?

Comment: Does your light tunnel project out as a tube and sit flat? I have one like that and it also has a reflector to reflect the sun and project more light down.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference as your question is worded. The sun rises in the east and sets in the west, so half the day it will be on one side, and half the day it will be on the other.

Consider timing how long the sun is hitting each roof since there could be obstructions, a slight angle north or south, or other factor we can't help with here. Note that the sun will be shifting in the sky throughout the year, so don't be too precise with these measurements. Also consider what times of the day you'd like the most light, whether you're a morning person, or will be home and awake for longer in the evening.